# Computer screen intermittently turns off

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, hp

My computer screen randomly turns black while the system is in use, and remains so for a bit before turning back on again. However, there's an interesting component to this issue which I believe is relevant for troubleshooting this. My night-light setting is no longer turned on when the screen comes back to life. Additionally, I have noticed that all audio and visual playback stops when the screen dies. What can be a likely cause and a fix to this problem?

I am running Windows 10 on a relatively new HP laptop. Power-saving mode is usually not enabled; the device usually runs on high-performance mode.

Comment: I have already run many of the in-built troubleshooters to no avail. All updates have been installed

Comment: Sounds like your graphics driver is crashing. Check Windows Event Viewer, probably in the System log.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean your laptop built-in display, this looks like a hardware issue, because you say audio playback also stops -- Most common reason for this is that the laptop thinks you closed the lid.

Since you say your laptop is relatively new, may or may not be a defect. I had this experience before, where my laptop uses a magnetic sensor to detect lid closure, and my watch band has a magnetic buckle. Every time my hand with the watch slips aside my laptop it thinks I am closing the lid...

Some laptops uses a pressure sensor close to the pivot to detect lid closure. If your laptop is like this, then you need to make sure that small rod sticking out of the keyboard/screen is not stuck or broken.

---

If this is not the case, we might need some additional troubleshooting to find where the issue is. One quick way is to create a Ubuntu (or whatever Linux dist you like) live USB with desktop (GUI), and use that for a while long enough to see if the similar issue recurs. This helps us find if the issue is with hardware or with just your Windows.

If it is with Windows, then we need to find if it is generally with Windows, or just with your installation of Windows. If it is related to display adapter, etc., try enter Safe Mode of Windows, which disables most of the third-party drivers, to see if issue recurs.

Comment: It doesn't seem like my PC is thinking I closed the lid, because that does not explain why the night light feature resets to its default off setting.

Comment: I've seen it happen quite regularly that the default windows night light 'breaks' after coming out of sleep mode. The lid closing would be like going into sleep mode. You could check the windows event logs to see what event was triggered.

Comment: I see. Where exactly should I be looking in the event log?

Comment: @Shane Aside checking system logs, can you also try to change "closing lid" operation to "do nothing" and see if that helps? Note: Screen might still go black in such case, but if night light was broken due to sleep then it might have different symptoms.

Comment: This discussion: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/logging-power-events-sleep-wake-up-to-the-event/e004a68c-f9a9-4982-86ba-a1cee05f9e4d contains some useful info about debugging sleep/wake-up events. @Shane